# How to profile Haskell after compiler optimizations?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a fairly complex and performance-critical Haskell program. I have used cost center profiling to optimize to the point where there are no major remaining hot spots. Furthermore, the program runs about 15x faster with `-O2` (and no profiling) than it does with `stack build --profile`, so I have doubts as to whether the cost center profiler is helping much at all with finding bottlenecks that remain post-optimization.

What are my options for finding hot spots that remain after optimization? I am aware of ticky-ticky profiling, but it is described in the docs as not for "mere mortals", and I am a mere mortal.

Comment: I think this may be too broad, although it would be great to have a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @jberryman I don't see how I can make the question narrower; in order to ask how to make X faster (where X is a specific task that is running slowly), I first need to figure out what X is.  Surely this is a common need..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GHC 9.4.1 you can use the [`-fprof-late`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.4.1/docs/users_guide/profiling.html#ghc-flag--fprof-late) flag to have the compiler add automatic cost centre annotations after optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very general question, but do you have searched for space leaks ?

One nice package is [weigh](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/weigh).

The author has written a very good [article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/05/weigh-package) about it.